# Pass data to uib-accordion-group

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I Have the following code:

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="isOpen" template-url="group-template.html">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
        Custom Title
    </uib-accordion-heading>

</div>
```

In `group-template.html` I have this code:

```
<h4 class="panel-title" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
    <span uib-accordion-header>{{heading}}</span>
    <div ng-switch="varCondition">
        <i class="a" ng-switch-when="1"/>
        <i class="b" ng-switch-when="2"/>
    </div>
</h4>
```

How can I pass the `varCondition` variable as the `template-url` parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the html-template try changing

```
ng-switch="varCondition"
```

Into

```
ng-switch="$parent.varCondition"
```

[Here is a working plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/geYZApFcz5PBKnAm)